# Why aren't any dinosaurs written in the bible?

Tags: science

Did they really exist before men? Or co-existed with man in the early ages? Where did the fossils came from and why isn't it written in the bible?

Comment: Good question! Though for this site you probably want to narrow it down so it stays within the confines of Christianity and the Bible (and historical scientific observation).

Comment: Not all Christian denominations believe that all parts of the Bible are 100% historically accurate, and conversely believe that there are parts of history which are not reflected in the Bible. This will affect an answer to your question from their point of view.

Comment: Welcome to the site. We are glad you decided to participate. For future reference please see the [question types that the community finds acceptable.](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/3409/types-of-questions-or-template-questions-that-the-community-generally-finds-ac) If possible, write all future questions to fit into one of those question types. I hope to see you post again soon.

Comment: **Mod Notice:** Knock it off guys! Comments are not for debating issues, much less poking fun at each-other. They are for asking for or suggesting improvements to posts. End of story.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read Genesis chapter one you will see that, all of the beasts and man on the sixth day.

> Genesis 1:24 through 31  And God said, Let the earth bring forth the living creature after his kind, cattle, and creeping thing, and beast of the earth after his kind: and it was so. 25  And God made the beast of the earth after his kind, and cattle after their kind, and every thing that creepeth upon the earth after his kind: and God saw that it was good. 26  And God said, Let us make man in our image, after our likeness: and let them have dominion over the fish of the sea, and over the fowl of the air, and over the cattle, and over all the earth, and over every creeping thing that creepeth upon the earth. 27  So God created man in his own image, in the image of God created he him; male and female created he them. 28  And God blessed them, and God said unto them, Be fruitful, and multiply, and replenish the earth, and subdue it: and have dominion over the fish of the sea, and over the fowl of the air, and over every living thing that moveth upon the earth. 29  And God said, Behold, I have given you every herb bearing seed, which is upon the face of all the earth, and every tree, in the which is the fruit of a tree yielding seed; to you it shall be for meat. 30  And to every beast of the earth, and to every fowl of the air, and to every thing that creepeth upon the earth, wherein there is life, I have given every green herb for meat: and it was so. 31  And God saw every thing that he had made, and, behold, it was very good. And the evening and the morning were the sixth day.

These websites may be of some help to you:

Ancient Dinosaur Depictions | Genesis Park

Prehistoric Cave Art Depicting Humans Hunting Dinosaurs ...

Alleged Dinosaurs and in Ancient Art

Ancient Dinosaur Depictions

Answer (score 2):

- Did they really exist before men?

Yes, undoubtedly. There is ample evidence that dinosaurs ceased to exist around 65 million years ago, long before the arrival of humans.

- Or co-existed with man in the early ages?

No, modern humans did not come on the scene until around 200,000 years ago. Even the earliest hominids are dated less than 7 million years old. For example, David Lambert, *in The Field Guide to Early Man*,  describes AustraIopithecus afarensis, which evolved perhaps 4 million years ago from a late dryopithecine, dying out by 2.5 million years ago. The famous 'Lucy' skeleton was a member of this group, which stood about 1.3 metres tall. Carbon dating can give reliable dates up to only about 50,000 years, but various other methods take us back further. For example, a non-radio-active technique involves amino-acid racemisation, which occurs in organisms after death and can be used with bone to 100,000 years old and more.

- Where did the fossils came from?

Dinosaur fossils are found at various depths, sometimes more than a kilometre below the surface. Consistently, the lower the fossil is in the geological column, the more primitive the species. Some argue that the dinosaurs were all killed in the biblical Flood and that the fossils are the remains of this great event, but then we should not see such clear stratification from ancient to more modern species; moreover we should even see human skeletons mixed in with those of dinosaurs.  An alleged print of a dinosaur's footprint and that of a human has been shown to be fraudulent.

- and why isn't it written in the Bible?

Dinosaurs are not mentioned in the Bible because the ancients were unaware of them. The Bible does mention two chaos monsters that also featured in the mythologies of other Near Eastern civilisations, but belief in chaos monsters is not the same as awareness of dinosaurs, of which there were thousands of species, large and small. Othmar Keel and Christoph Uehlinger, in *Gods, Goddesses, and Images of God*, page 43, explains that Baal was acclaimed in Canaan as victor over Litanu / Leviathan, the chaos monster depicted as a reptile. In the Book of Job, we find that God was the victor over Leviathan.

Comment: I would love to know why this answer has been down-voted.

Comment: @gideon marx I think many votes are based on emotion, not logic